# Excel Index & Match using a Boolean OR with Wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data:

(Columns A and B)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apples & Dates | £1.20 |
| Oranges | £0.50 |
| Pears | £3.55 |
| Melons | £4.44 |

I want to do index match on the first column to find cells that contain "Apples" OR "Dates".

When I try this:

```
=INDEX(A1:B3,MATCH(1,(A1:A3="*"&"apples"&"*")+(A1:A3="*"&"dates"&"*"),0),2)
```

(I press ctrl-shift-enter to put it as an array) I still get the #N/A problem

What am i missing? (I have tried Xlookup but gives the same problem. If i try and just put a single array in of `=(A1:A3="*"&"apples"&"*")` it still fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(A1:A3="*"&"apples"&"*")+(A1:A3="*"&"dates"&"*")` If `IF` worked with wildcards (Hint: It does not) would return `2` not `1` when it hits `A1` and therefore it will not find a match.

But if you have XLOOKUP, you have FILTER and FILTER will do what you want:

```
=@FILTER(B1:B4,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",A1:A4)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dates",A1:A4))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can i use a Indirect with the filter, e.g. Filter(Indirect("B"&E1):B4.... for instance?

Comment: do not use INDIRECT if it can be avoided:  `=@FILTER(INDEX(B:B,E1):B4,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",INDEX(A:A,E1):A4)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dates",INDEX(A:A,E1):A4))))`

Comment: Thanks, but my index column (lets use the table above) of B1:B3 could very well be C1:C3 so i need to be able to alter the column which I thought would be best via Indirect

Comment: Then use `INDEX(A:ZZ,E1,E2):INDEX(A:ZZ,E3,E2)` where E1 is the start row, E2 is the column NUMBER and E3 is the end row number.

Comment: Indirect is volatile and should be avoided.

Comment: And that's in place of the original Filter(B1:B4)???  so instead it should read:

=@FILTER(INDEX(A:ZZ,E1,E2):INDEX(A:ZZ,E3,E2),(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",A1:A4)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dates",A1:A4))))

Where E1 is the start row, E2 is column number and E3 is the end row number?

Comment: You will need to change the `A:A` to `INDEX(A:A,E1):INDEX(A:A,E3)` so it is the same size.

Comment: `INDEXSheet2!(A:A,E1):INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,E3)`